# Strong convergence in $L^1$ and weak-star convergence in $L^\infty$ implies strong convergence in $L^2$?

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis

I have a question regarding converging subsequences.
In a paper I am reading it says:

Let $\Omega$ be an open bounded domain with Lipschitz boundary $\partial \Omega$ and $T >0 $.

Since a subsequence $u_n(\cdot,t) \rightarrow u(\cdot,t)$ strongly in $L^1(\Omega)$ for each $t\in [0,\infty)$
and the subsequence $u_n \rightharpoonup u$ weak-* converges in $L^\infty (\Omega \times [0,\infty))$, this implies that there exists a subsequence(denoted by the same notation) $u_n \rightarrow u$ strongly in $L^2(0,T;L^2(\Omega))$.

Why does this hold? They don't give an argument for that.

Kind regards

Comment: Weak* convergence implies boundedness in the norm of $L^{\infty}$ from which $L^{2}$ convergence is clear.

Comment: For me it is not clear, does it hold because of a kind of Hölder inequality? I would like to write it down formally but I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: yes, use Hoelder inequality

Comment: $|f_n-f|^{2} =|f_n-f||f_n+f| \leq 2M|f_n-f|$ if $|f_n| \leq M$ a.e.

Comment: I made a small mistake but you can make the correction easily.

Comment: I don't see the mistake. Where should it be?

Answer (score 1):

For completeness, I give the corrected solution. It was claimed in the comments that $|f_n-f|^{2} =|f_n-f||f_n+f| \leq 2M|f_n-f|$ when $|f_n|\le M$ (and hence $|f|\le M$). But the first step is correct instead for $|f_n^2 - f^2|$. The correct argument should instead use triangle inequality $|f_n - f| \le |f_n| + |f|$, i.e.
$$ |f_n-f|^2 \le (|f_n| +|f|)|f_n-f| \le 2M |f_n - f|.$$